# Letter Shift with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP function that Ciphers a string using a letter shift down or up the alphabet using a value of their choice.

This is what I have so far:

```
function encrypt($in, $n) {
    $in = strtolower($in);
    $let = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");
    $num = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");
    $negnum = array("-26", "-25", "-24", "-23", "-22", "-21", "-20", "-19", "-18", "-17", "-16", "-15", "-14", "-13", "-12", "-11", "-10", "-9", "-8", "-7", "-6", "-5", "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1");
    $nums = str_replace($let, $num, $in);
    $temp = str_split($nums, 1);
    foreach($temp as &$v) {
        $v = ($v + $n);
        if($v == 0 or $v > 0){
            $v = str_replace($num, $let, $v);
        } else {
            $v = str_replace($negnum, $let, $v);
        }   
    }
    return implode('', $temp);
}

echo encrypt('EPPEABBOADBFTBS', '-3');
```

In it's current state the function is really not working - outputting strings that don't fit the value and also repeating letters of the string.

Am I going around this in the right way?

Please let me know,

Brad

Comment: Take a look at some of the custom versions of str_rot13 - http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php which do this without needing those arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier to use `ord` and `chr`:

```
function shift($string, $distance) {
    $distance = $distance % 26;
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $result = array();
    $characters = str_split($string);

    if ($distance < 0) {
        $distance += 26;
    }

    foreach ($characters as $idx => $char) {
        $result[$idx] = chr(97 + (ord($char) - 97 + $distance) % 26);
    }   

    return join("", $result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to also be able to make the shift value negative.

Answer (score 0):

[strtr — Translate characters or replace substrings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 0):

```php
function shift($string, $distance) {
    $result = [];
    $characters = str_split($string);

    foreach ($characters as $idx => $char) {
        $result[$idx] = chr(ord($char) + $distance);
    }   

    return join("", $result);
}
```

This works with all characters (not limiting itself to alphabet), but that also means that the shifted string may not be printable as-is.

However you can see it works by shifting something by arbitrary value (within reason), and then shifting it back with the same function and reverse distance.

Ideal for cooperating with C code that can easily arbitrarily shift individual characters.

If you need to print the resulting string, consider using base64.